# Stored Procedure to update and compare Salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to display the current and updated salary for my stored procedure.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Increasemypay
     @percent_increase float
 AS
 BEGIN  
     SELECT @percent_increase, Salary
     FROM TEACHER
     WHERE Salary = @percent_increase

     SET @percent_increase = 0.07

     UPDATE teacher 
         SELECT 
             FROM TEACHER
         WHERE Salary = @percent_increase;
 GO
```

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And what is your question? What does/doesn't work about your SP? Are you trying to update every record with the salary increase? BTW I highly recommend not using float for a percentage, float is for scientific data and doesn't always accurately store decimal data.

Comment: And once again - date of birth is a DATE, not a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just display the current and new proposed salary side by side then:

```
Select Salary, Salary * (1.0 + @percent_increase)
    From TEACHER
```